# which is better gem for solr cloud setup in rails 4.1 application for aws hosting,I had researched some gems as below

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, solr, solrcloud, rsolr

which is better gem for solr cloud setup in rails 4.1 application for aws hosting,I have done research on the below gems .

```
  gem 'rsolr-cloud',
  gem 'rsolr',
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

which is the best setup for **solr cloud setup** in aws hosting using elastic beanstalk.Please give me any suggestions with some documents or examples.

Thanks in advance.